# Use of UIBarButtonSystemItemAction

Tags: uikit, hig

A lot of people I talked to seem to think action button (UIBarButtonSystemItemAction) is for Share or Export functionalities (e.g. like its use in the Photos app).

[image]

According to HIG, this meaning of button is to:

> "Open a modal view that lists system-provided and app-provided actions
>   that can work with the current content."

Question - what do you use this button for in your app?